# "Initially moving" or "moving initially"

Tags: word-order

It seems correct to say

> The casualty count was initially reported to be 50.

But while “The box was initially moving to the left” sounds correct, what about this sentence?

> The box was initially moving.

And which of these is correct?

> The casualty count was initially reported to be 50.    *OR*
>   The casualty count was initially reported as 50.

Comment: We could address this more usefully if you explained where you see a difficulty in these sentences.

Comment: *The box was initially moving* sounds like a statement of initial conditions in a physics problems (and perfectly grammatical): *I computed the final velocity as 50 m/s. I assumed the box was initially moving because the person dropped it from the moving train as it went over the bridge.*

Comment: I think this question is confusing because it's actually asking two questions: 1) what is the preferred/correct location of "initially"? 2) is it correct to say "report as"? The second question is readily answered [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/report_1)

Answer (score 1):

"The box was initially moving." is a perfectly fine sentence grammatically, but it might not make much sense in most contexts. Like Jim mentioned in the comments, this would probably be most likely seen in a physics word problem.

I'm not an expert, but I do believe the last two sentences are also fine. I don't know if you're looking at a multiple choice question which forces you to pick between those two sentences, but if I had to guess, I would pick the first one. My reasoning is that although the second sentence looks correct, it's somewhat unusual to replace an infinitive with "as." I do think the second sentence *is correct*, mind you, I'm just not sure if it's a forced choice (since you capitalized and italicized the "or"). I believe it's being used as a preposition here, and it's in accordance with this definition:

> 2. In a manner similar to; the same as: On this issue they thought as one.

My reasoning here being that the structure of this example sentence and your last two sentences is the same around the word "as."

Source: The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition copyright ©2000 by Houghton Mifflin Company. Updated in 2009. Published by Houghton Mifflin Company. All rights reserved.

Answer (score 0):

"initially " is adverb so in context: They are moving  initially to NEW York

city.

"initial " is adjective that means first : Initial sales figures have been very

good.IS your initial moving to NEW YORK city ?

Comment: I can parse "Is your initial moving New York City?" but it seems awkward / unidiomatic.

Comment: Adding *to* to *Is your initial moving **to** New York City?* makes me unable to parse it anymore.

Comment: I think it should be *"Is your initial move to New York City"*. A general rule is: don't use gerunds as nouns if there's an existing noun in English that works better. In this case, it confused people.